# Shoulld I decode JWT only on auth server?

Tags: http, architecture

I am designing an architecture for my application. I plan on having 2 servers: `auth` and `main`. Auth server is responsible signing and issuing `access` tokens.

`auth` and `main` are on different servers and communicate via HTTP requests. With this setup, I have no way to verify `access_token` of the `main` server, since only `auth` has the secret key. I'd have to send user's JWT to verify on `auth` on every request.

This means I no longer have simple `client->main` and instead have `client->main->auth`. This seems like a bad idea because it essentially doubles the number of total requests made.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: So, the best solution to this seems to be using an asymmetric signing algorithm (like RS256). How common is this?